# Troubleshooting why I need to frequently run sp_refreshview

Tags: sql-server-2017

I'm an accidental dba for our ERP database (SQL Server 2017). ERP had become unresponsive for a user and I determined that a query running against a view was running very slowly.  I thought it might be related to a recently installed vendor service pack.  I tried running sp_refreshview against the view, and the query ran quickly again.

The odd thing is, the problem keeps coming back even when we haven't been running any updates that would change the tables the view relies on.  Each time running sp_refreshview gets things running normally again.  I added the call to sp_refreshview to the nightly maintenance job but that didn't eliminate the problem.

I'm looking for suggestions on how to identify what is causing this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: My initial thought is that sp_refreshview probably (I'd need to test to be sure) invalidates the query plan for the query running against the view causing a recompile on the next execution and it is getting a more suitable plan. I would need to do some testing to verfiy this though. Can you share the code for the query calling the view?

Comment: @SEarle1986 I'm almost certain you're correct on that. This does stink of a bad cached query plan, perhaps due to **parameter sniffing** or another **cardinality estimate** driven reason. dgc, if you could please update your post with the **actual execution plan** of the slow running query that would be helpful in debugging this. (Additionally the **actual execution plan** of the fast running query would be a bonus, for comparing against.)

Comment: Please also add the table *and index* definitions, as well as the full query

Comment: I ran the problem by the ERP vendor, and the slow reads from the view are a known issue.  They've been recommending rebuilding the indexes on the tables the view uses. (The Ola Hallengren maintenance script I've been using has been ignoring these indexes since the page counts are less than 1000.  I just added a step to address the other indexes)  The vendor didn't say anything about using sp_refreshview.  I understand the need for more details.  Unfortunately, I don't have the query readily available.  If the problem happens again, I'll put together the requested information.

Comment: @dgc Rebuilding indexes will have the same effect as sp_refreshview - it will invalidate queries in the cache that reference that view and cause a recompile, appearing to fix the problem until it picks a bad plan again